# name collision use 'from import' and I can't use the variable that is imported?

Tags: python

So for example: here I have `fake.py` file and `real.py` file. And in `fake.py`:

```
a = 'fake a'
b = 'fake b'
```

and in `real.py`:

```
from fake import*
a = 'real a'
print(a,b)
```

then it prints out: `real a fake b`

Why is that?
What if I want to use `a` in `fake.py`?
Do I have to use `import fake` and `fake.a`?

> 'statements within a module(fake in this example?) are executed only the first time a module is imported'

what does this mean ?

I am new to programming please help thank you.

Comment: Then don't use `from module import *`

Comment: See [Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/10077)

Comment: Yes, this is why you shouldn't use `from module import *`

Comment: For added fun, swap the order of `from fake import*` and `a = 'real a'`. Then imagine you have 10,000 lines of code with this buried somewhere inside and how you keep track of what `a` is supposed to be (even if it had a more meaningful name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep away from `from some_module import *` because you import all names from that module into your current module namespace.

This will - in case of a "name clash" - not only overwrite any previously defined names but they are also, as you've seen, likely to be overwritten.

---

> Why is that?

The `from fake import *` in your case is *very roughly* equivalent to:

```
# equivalent to "from fake import *"
import fake
a = fake.a
b = fake.b
del fake

# Rest of the file
a = "real a"
print(a, b)
```

So no wonder that the `"fake a"` isn't accessible (nor printed).

---

> Do I have to use `import fake` and `fake.a`?

That's a good start if you want to "reduce" the likelyhood of such name collisions:

```
import fake
a = "real a"
print(a, fake.a, fake.b)
```

But you could also use an alias:

```
import fake as f
a = "real a"
print(a, f.a, f.b)
```

You could also import specific names from `fake` (also with aliases):

```
from fake import a as fake_a, b as fake_b
a = "real a"
print(a, fake_a, fake_b)
```

---

As for

> What if I want to use `a` in `fake.py`?

There should be no problem because there is no import in `fake.py` so no name collision there.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

You are importing two global variables from fake.py (a & b) and then assigning a new value to one of them (a).

## Solution

If you would like to use fake.a and fake.b then get rid of the * in the import directive. Use this import directive:

```
import fake
```

Then you will be able to access the a & b variable with this form

```
fake.a
fake.b
```